# SwiftUI get total item (row in SQL terms) count from Core Data entity

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui, entity, nsfetchrequest

Using SwiftUI (2021) XCode 13.1 / iOS 14.5+ and Core Data I am trying to get the most efficient total count within an entity.

This from an SQL perspective is like getting the total number of rows from a table.

The Entity will never contain many 'rows' probably never more than 40.

I have Googled lots of examples (including here) but some are old and most don't work. It seems to be something to do with countForFetchRequest but in that I'm not 100% sure.

I have already configured the container  and entity that simply contains an id field and a text field.

I'm still new to Core Data so hopefully I have the terminology correct but from various examples this is what I have come up with. (noting I need the data to persist after the app is closed).

```swift
import CoreData

class FooCoreDataService {
    
    private let container: NSPersistentContainer
    private let containerName: String = "FooCoreDataModel"
    private let entityName: String = "FooEntity"
    
    init() {
    
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: containerName)
    
        container.loadPersistentStores { (_, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error loading Core Data! \(error)")
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    // Get total item ('Row') count of FooEntity 
    func getFooCount() -> Int {
        
        var countOfItems: Int = 0
        
        // NOT SURE WHAT GOES HERE
        
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest ????
        
        // SOMETHING TO DO WITH countForFetchRequest ????
        
        
        return countOfItems
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you need?

```
static func getFooCount() -> Int {
   let object = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
   let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Product")
   let countOfItems = try! object.count(for: fetchRequest)
   return countOfItems
}
```